# require ruby-oci8 results in a OCI.dll not found error

Tags: ruby, oracle, rubymine, oci8

I am using

ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

and have the gem ruby-oci8 (2.2.5 x86-mingw32) installed
also have instantclient andsqlplus loaded and working on my computer.

using IRB I can

```
 require 'oci8'
 OCI8.new('user/pwd@//host:port/sid')
 con = OCI8.new(connectString)
 statement = 'SELECT * from TBL
 cursor = con.parse(statement)
 cursor.exec
 cursor.fetch() {|row| puts row}
```

However when I run from IRB in RubyMind IDE or VisualCode where I have bundle 
then I get the following error

```
 LoadError: OCI.DLL: 161(The specified path is invalid.  )
```

I have confirmed that the OCI.DLL is included in my PATH